# How can I use jBPM in my GWT application?

Tags: gwt, integration, jbpm

I have a GWT Project and I need to use a workflow framework to control my business process (BP). I see that jBPM have one console made in GWT but it's a simple a console to control jBPM BP. I need a way to import jars in my GWT project and use the jBPM notations in my code to control my internal BP and not use the jBPM engine to run my app. It is possible? If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jBPM runtime engine could be considered just as a set of jar files. JBoss Developer Studio/JBoss Tools can either

- create new jBPM runtime and provide you with such jars, which can be then copied to your GWT project: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMEclipseJBPM.html#d0e14020
- or, add them as maven dependencies: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMEclipseJBPM.html#d0e14069